# How to use input mask in Javascript for username & Mac ID

Tags: javascript, imaskjs

I want to filter username & Mac id from one input field... if the string starts with '00' then put a colon after every two integers & characters & if it starts with alphabets did not put a colon after two characters...

```js
var dynamicMask = new IMask(document.getElementById('user'), {
  mask: [{
      mask: '00:00:00:00:00:00'
    },
    {
      mask: /^\S*@?\S*$/
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Username or Mac id</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Enter ..." />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of 0 and * to mask both numbers and letters

```js
var dynamicMask = new IMask(document.getElementById('user'), {
    mask: [{
      mask: '0*:**:**:**:**:**'
    },
    {
      mask: /^\S*@?\S*$/
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Username or Mac id</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Enter ..." />
</div>
```

Comment: problem is that it's working on username.....

Comment: if I write alphabets result is in this form 'df:sf:sd:fs:df'

Comment: So you want to mask only the numbers? If so, what's the problem in your code? that was working fine in that scenario.

Comment: in mac id, there is also alphabets... so in my code when I write alphabets in mac id  it removes all colon

Comment: I have updated the answer, let me know if that helps

Comment: its Working fine ... Thank you

Comment: if the username is in integer form so what are the changes in the code?

Comment: There is no way to differentiate between id and username if both stats with same type of latter. You have to keep the input separate for both values.

Comment: if we identify the mac id with any special character like '@00:5F:56:7B:34:76' we wrote like that in the input field....then code easily understand this is a number or mac id...